# How to relate a user to Django-avatar plugin?

Tags: django, avatar

I am new to Django and trying to create a registration form for users. I want users to upload there image during signup. After some research I got django-avatar and easy thumbnail as way to go, am I correct? So I went ahead with django-avatar but I am confused how to add a form field to userprofile that talks to django avatar. Am I in correct path or should I use some other plugin for uplaoding an user image. If Django-avatar is the way to go how should I create a form field for image and how my view look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/formsets/) with the form set to `avatar.forms.UploadAvatarForm`

Comment: How should I relate my user to the avatar image?

Comment: the avatar image model already relates to the user. https://github.com/mbertrand/django-avatar/blob/master/avatar/models.py#L69

Comment: Is there a good documentation for Django avatar apart from [this](https://github.com/jezdez/django-avatar)? I really having hard time trying to implement this. I am unable to load the url patterns `import avatar urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    (r'^avatar/', include('avatar.urls')),
)'`. But my local server is showing the url not matching error.

Comment: `1.^avatar/
2.^static\/(?P<path>.*)$`
I guess its something to do with my static files directory, but I have a Media_root set in settings.Also I have `AVATAR_STORAGE_DIR = MEDIA_ROOT + 'avatars/'`